# Ruby hash to another hash with certain keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash like this

```
[{"user_id"=>"4672046155508aafb4d01bca27cca8c6", "email"=>"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "sport"=>[nil]}, {"user_id"=>"007ba6fd74b3ef3c12734ddd0f2280ae", "email"=>"xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com", "sport"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil]}, {"user_id"=>"0085e4d74738a384e10042b62acb56e2", "email"=>"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "sport"=>[nil, nil, nil]}]
```

I need a hash with all email in it , How to do this?...whenever I use

```
  users[:email]
```

It gives the error cannot convert symbol to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
hash_array = [{"user_id"=>"4672046155508aafb4d01bca27cca8c6", "email"=>"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "sport"=>[nil]}, {"user_id"=>"007ba6fd74b3ef3c12734ddd0f2280ae", "email"=>"xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com", "sport"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil]}, {"user_id"=>"0085e4d74738a384e10042b62acb56e2", "email"=>"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "sport"=>[nil, nil, nil]}]
hash_array.map{ |hash| hash["email"] }
```

It will return an array of all the emails

Answer (score 0):

It isn't hash, it's an array of hashes. To access first hash `email`, you can do:

```
users.first['email']
```